# Anti-Forgery Token Validation in MVC app with Blazor Server-side Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

With ASP.NET Core 3.0 out, I am trying to leverage server-side Blazor capabilities in my MVC Core app.
I've started by creating a simple navigation component, from which I am trying to let users sign out with a button that points at a controller action. However, I am running into an Anti-Forgery Token Validation error that reads:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.

And then the server returns an HTTP 400 status code.

I'm following the Blazor App template code (Blazor version 0.7.0 with Visual Studio 2019):

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <form method="post" action="/Account/Logout">
            <button type="submit">Sign out</button>
        </form>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        <a href="/Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

My MVC `Account` Controller has a Logout action annotated with *`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`*, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

In the past, I would add a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in a form to conform with my annotated Logout action. In newer versions of ASP.NET Core you no longer needed to add this manually, as it is included within form tag helpers. But neither approach seems to translate or be available in a Blazor component.

How would you call this MVC action from a Blazor component and provide the Anti-forgery token for the controller validation?
Or is this validation not needed at all anymore?

Even if my sign out case is not a big threat, this would be the same for calling any other action annotated similarly.

I might be missing a technical concept of CSRF that applies to the scenario of mixing MVC and Blazor.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11787 - CSRF tokens aren't involved in a server-side Blazor circuit, since CSRF is about protecting from unexpected third-party HTTP requests, whereas a server-side Blazor circuit exists within a WebSocket connection.

Comment: @Dennis1679, Thanks. What would that mean in this scenario? That I should remove the annotation from the action? wouldn't that make that action vulnerable? It's still and MVC app.

Comment: You know, I was going to say that Steve Sanderson (A member of the .net team) can be trusted when he says that CSRF isn't an issue. But, after reading the section on security by Microsoft, it looks like even a malicious WebSocket can be created. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/server?view=aspnetcore-3.0#protect-information-in-transit-with-https

Answer (score 14):

I have been trying to get anti-forgery to work for a Logout POST. I think I just managed to get it working. I'm open to suggestions for improvements!

I used an MS doc on [Blazor Server additional security scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which explains a method for storing OIDC access and refresh tokens for use in Blazor components. I modified that example in order to use an anti-forgery token in a similar way as follows:

1. I created a `TokenProvider` class to store the anti-forgery token.

```cs
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AntiforgeryToken { get; set; }
}
```

2. Added a Scoped `TokenProvider` to DI in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
    ...
}
```

3. Got the anti-forgery token in `_Host.cshtml` and passed it as a parameter to my `App` component

```cs
@page "/"
@namespace My.Pages
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery antiforgery
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;
}
...
<body>
  <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-AntiforgeryToken="token" />
...
```

4. `App.razor` then populates the `TokenProvider` during `OnInitializedAsync()`

```cs
@inject TokenProvider tokenProvider

<Router ....
</Router>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string AntiforgeryToken { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        tokenProvider.AntiforgeryToken = AntiforgeryToken;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

5. `TokenProvider` can then be consumed via injection in my `Logout.razor` Component

```cs
@inject TokenProvider tokenProvider
...
<form method="post" action="Logout">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="@tokenProvider.AntiforgeryToken">
    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link" title="Log out">
        <span class="oi oi-account-logout"></span>
    </button>
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this Exception popped up. This worked for me though.
Just add this to the end of your _Host.cshtml file.

```
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</body>
```